# how does the 'mean_cl_normal function' from Hmisc work?

Tags: r

what are the internals of `mean_cl_normal function` and is it safe to use for confidence intervals calculation? How does it work in detail?

Answer (score 8):

`mean_cl_normal` is part of `ggplot`. It uses `smean.cl.normal(...)` in Hmisc, which uses quantiles of the t-distribution to calculate confidence limits.

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducibility
x <- rnorm(100, mean=5)
library(Hmisc)
smean.cl.normal(x)
#     Mean    Lower    Upper 
# 5.108887 4.930665 5.287110 
mean(x) + c(0,1,-1) * qt(0.05/2,(length(x)-1))*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
# [1] 5.108887 4.930665 5.287110
```